# v-bind not working in a form input during production

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I seem to have run into a very strange issue with v-bind. I am trying to populate some hidden form fields with data from some URL parameters. I have been trying to use v-bind to update the value of the hidden fields before they are submitted to Netlify. An example field looks like this:

```
<input id="utm_campaign" :key="utm_campaign" type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" :value="utm_campaign" />
```

and is updated like this:

```
export default {
  name: "Contact",
  data() {
    return {
      utm_source: "none",
      utm_medium: "none",
      utm_campaign: "none",
      ready: false
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log("created");
    this.utm_source = this.$route.query.utm_source;
    this.utm_medium = this.$route.query.utm_medium;
    this.utm_campaign = this.$route.query.utm_campaign;
    console.log(this.$route.query.utm_source);
    console.log(this.$route.query.utm_medium);
    console.log(this.$route.query.utm_medium);
    this.ready = true;
    this.$forceUpdate();
  }
};
```

When I inspect the field on my local it looks like this:

(the URL is http://localhost:3000/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=retarget&utm_campaign=conversion)

```
<input data-v-115426d6="" id="utm_campaign" type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="conversion">
```

Yet, for whatever reason, it looks like this once deployed:

```
<input id="utm_campaign" type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" data-v-231118a1="">
```

I'm at a loss for what to do. I've tried forcing a reload with this.$forceUpdate(), I've added the :key to each field, I've even tried using the forbidden v-if method of reloading once the variable 'ready' changes. Nothing seems to work! I would greatly appreciate any help.

This is all running on Nuxt.js, deployed on Netlify.

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Marketing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/content": "^1.11.1",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1637745161.ea53f98",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/toast": "^3.3.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.4",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.12",
    "rellax": "^1.12.1",
    "v-calendar": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.6.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^5.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you log `this.$route.query.utm_campaign` ?

Comment: Also, can you post your package.json? One guess is that there's a difference between how the code is packaged between "npm run serve" and "npm run build"

Comment: I can log utm_campaign as well, that was a typo in the logging step above that I just corrected. I just added my package.json. Thank you for the help!!!